# Helm V3 - Cannot find the official repo

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-deployment

I have been trying to install nginx ingress using helm version 3

```
helm install my-ingress stable/nginx-ingress
```

But Helm doesn't seem to be able to find it's official `stable` repo. It gives the message:

> Error: failed to download "stable/nginx-ingress" (hint: running `helm
>   repo update` may help)

---

I tried `helm repo update`. But it doesn't help.

I tried listing the repos `helm repo list` but it is empty.

---

I tried to add the stable repo:

```
helm repo add stable https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable
```

But it fails with:

> Error: looks like "https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable"
>   is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch
>   https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/index.yaml : 404 Not
>   Found

Comment: @MWZ How is it a duplicate of a question which says `--name` flag is unknown?

Comment: @MWZ One question should discuss one problem.

Comment: @MWZ This is in absolutely no way a duplicate of that question. 100% unrelated.

Answer (score 192, accepted):

The `stable` repository is hosted on https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/. So, try the following:

```
helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
```

**EDIT 2020-11-16:** the above repository seems to have been [deprecated](https://github.com/helm/charts#deprecation-timeline). The following should now work instead:

```
helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable
```

Comment: Will the repo in **google storage** continue to be available after [mentioned](https://github.com/helm/charts#deprecation-timeline) deprecation in stable charts repo?

Comment: Error: repo "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/" is no longer available; try "https://charts.helm.sh/stable" instead

Answer (score 7):

Be aware that Helm v3 does not have the use of Tiller.

**1. Install Helm v3:**

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/helm/helm/master/scripts/get-helm-3 > get_helm.sh
chmod 700 get_helm.sh
./get_helm.sh
```

**2. Install Ingress-Nginx:**

```
helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/
helm install my-nginx stable/nginx-ingress --set rbac.create=true
```

Answer (score 6):

From [Helm Blog](https://helm.sh/blog/new-location-stable-incubator-charts/) -

> On November 13, 2020 the stable and incubator charts repository will
> reach the end of development and become archives. You can find that
> many of the charts have moved to other, community managed,
> repositories. You can discover these on [the Artifact Hub](https://artifacthub.io/).

The best way to discover a chart by searching [the Artifact Hub](https://artifacthub.io/). And if you select `nginx-ingress` from ORG Helm, you can see the instruction for adding a repo.

```
helm repo add nginx-stable https://helm.nginx.com/stable
```

[image: Artifact Hub]

Comment: I'm getting `Error: nginx chart not found in repo https://helm.nginx.com/stable`

Comment: Works for me - 1) helm repo add nginx-stable https://helm.nginx.com/stable 2) helm repo update 3)helm install my-release nginx-stable/nginx-ingress     Check steps at 
https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/nginx/nginx-ingress

Comment: Interestingly it worked with this link: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami using Chart Sources

Answer (score 1):

Below solution worked for me.

```
# Below command is not working
$ helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/

Error: repo "https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com/" is no longer available; try "https://charts.helm.sh/stable" instead

#Try this one, it's wokring.
$ helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable

"stable" has been added to your repositories
```

Answer (score 0):

The stable repositories are in helm hub https://hub.helm.sh/charts

Install the nginx chart for nginx ingress

```
helm install bitnami/nginx --version 6.2.0
```

Comment: Error: looks like "https://hub.helm.sh/charts" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 2: mapping values are not allowed in this context

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem by putting in this line:

```
helm repo add stable https://charts.jetstack.io
```