# Error: failed to download "stable/mssql-linux" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Please see the command below:

```
helm install --name mymssql stable/mssql-linux --set acceptEula.value=Y --set edition.value=Developer
```

which I got from here: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/mssql-linux

After just one month it appears the --name is no longer needed so I now have (see here: [Helm install unknown flag --name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57961162/helm-install-unknown-flag-name)):

```
helm install mymssql stable/mssql-linux --set acceptEula.value=Y --set edition.value=Developer
```

The error I see now is:

```
Error: failed to download "stable/mssql-linux" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)
```

What is the problem?

**Update**

Following on from the answers; the command above now works, however I cannot connect to the database using SQL Studio Manager from my local PC.  The additional steps I have followed are:

1) `kubectl expose deployment` mymssql-mssql-linux --type=NodePort --name=mymssql-mssql-linux-service

2) `kubectl get service` - the below service is relevant here
mymssql-mssql-linux-service   NodePort    10.107.98.68             1433:32489/TCP   7s

3) Then try to connect to the database using SQL Studio Manager 2019:
Server Name: localhost,32489
Authentication: SQL Server Authentication
Login: sa
Password: I have tried: b64enc quote and MyStrongPassword1234

I cannot connect using SQL Studio Manager.

Comment: tried the helm repo update?

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu, when I run helm repo update it says: "Error: no repositories found. You must add one before updating".

Comment: are you using helm 3 or helm 2?

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu, v3.1.2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if the stable repo is added or not

```
helm repo list
```

If not then add

```
helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
helm repo update
```

And then run below to install mssql-linux

```
helm install mymssql stable/mssql-linux --set acceptEula.value=Y --set edition.value=Developer
```

Comment: Could you have a look at my revision.  I am trying to make sure that sql has installed properly - I am new to Kubernetes.

Comment: for the help clarifying things in the comments.  +1

Comment: what is the error you are getting...can you try port forward and connect to it for testing

Comment: Are you able to take a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137552/cannot-create-a-sql-server-2019-pod-but-can-create-an-sql-server-2017-pod-why ? Notice the error: "Error: The evaluation period has expired.".

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```sh
helm repo add stable https://kubernetes-charts.storage.googleapis.com
helm repo update
```

and then run your helm command.

Explanation:
Helm in version 3 does not have any repository added by default (helm v2 had stable repository add by default), so you need to add it manually.

Update:

- First of all, if you are using helm keep everything in helm values it makes thinks cleaner and easier to find it later rather than mixing kubeclt and helm - I am referring to exposing service via kubeclt.
- Ad. 1,2. You have to read some [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) to understand Kubernetes services.

  - With `expose` command and type `NodePort` you are exposing your MySQL server on port 32489 - in your case, on Kubernetes nodes. You can check IP of Kubernetes nodes with `kubectl get nodes -owide`, so your database is available on :32489. This approach is very tricky, it might work fine for PoC purposes, but this is not a recommended way especially on cloud-hosted Kubernetes. The same result you can achieve appending you helm command with `--set service.type=NodePort`.
- Ad. 3 For debugging purposes you can use `kubectl port-forward` to port forward traffic from container to your local machine. `kubectl port-forward deploymeny/mymssql-mssql-linux 1433` should do the trick and you should be able to connect to MySQL on `localhost:1433`.

Comment: Yeah, that appears to of worked - thanks.  Could you briefly explain what it is doing for me and future readers?

Comment: I hope this is enough

Comment: Could you have a look at my revision.  I am trying to make sure that sql has installed properly - I am new to Kubernetes.  +1 for the explanation.

Comment: Are you able to take a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61137552/cannot-create-a-sql-server-2019-pod-but-can-create-an-sql-server-2017-pod-why ? Notice the error: "Error: The evaluation period has expired.".

Answer (score 0):

In case if the chart you want to use is not published to hub you can install the package directly using the path to the unpacked chart directory.

For example (works for helm v3.2.4):

```
git clone https://github.com/helm/charts/
cd helm/charts/stable
helm install --name mymssql ./mssql-linux --set acceptEula.value=Y --set edition.value=Developer
```