# Cannot create a SQL Server 2019 pod, but can create an SQL Server 2017 pod. Why can't I create an SQL Server 2019 pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have tried following the instructions on this webpage: https://dbafromthecold.com/2019/02/20/creating-custom-sql-server-helm-charts/ i.e.

1) helm init
2) mkdir C:\Helm
3) cd C:\Helm
4) helm create testsqlchart
5) cd testsqlchart/templates
6) rm deployment.yaml
rm service.yaml
rm ingress.yaml

7) Re-create deployment.yaml: –

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sqlserver
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: sqlserver
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sqlserver1
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CTP2.2-ubuntu
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1433
        env:
        - name: SA_PASSWORD
          value: "Testing1122"
        - name: ACCEPT_EULA
          value: "Y"
```

8) Re-create service.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sqlserver-service
spec:
  ports:
  - name: sqlserver
    port: 1433
    targetPort: 1433
  selector:
    name: sqlserver
  type: LoadBalancer
```

9) cd C:\Helm

10) helm install ./testsqlchart --name testsqlserver

11) kubectl get pods

Why is the Pod in a state of error? Here is the result of: `kubectl describe pod sqlserver-68865dd9f8-7xrtp`

```
Name:           sqlserver-68865dd9f8-7xrtp
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           docker-desktop/192.168.65.3
Start Time:     Fri, 10 Apr 2020 10:22:24 +0100
Labels:         name=sqlserver
                pod-template-hash=68865dd9f8
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             10.1.1.11
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/sqlserver-68865dd9f8
Containers:
  sqlserver1:
    Container ID:   docker://ac6c42c381a8368d7e354ab385181a2d94754ebefddf9fb5412f232a2c8539e6
    Image:          mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CTP2.2-ubuntu
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server@sha256:5beefc726eab1546a05a6520cdea9a795e7f64287821393f29099b6c21379419
    Port:           1433/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    139
      Started:      Fri, 10 Apr 2020 10:28:12 +0100
      Finished:     Fri, 10 Apr 2020 10:28:13 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  6
    Environment:
      SA_PASSWORD:  Testing1122
      ACCEPT_EULA:  Y
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-bncbh (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-bncbh:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-bncbh
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                     From                     Message
  ----     ------     ----                    ----                     -------
  Normal   Scheduled  8m2s                    default-scheduler        Successfully assigned default/sqlserver-68865dd9f8-7xrtp to docker-desktop
  Normal   Pulled     6m30s (x5 over 8m1s)    kubelet, docker-desktop  Container image "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-CTP2.2-ubuntu" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    6m30s (x5 over 8m1s)    kubelet, docker-desktop  Created container sqlserver1
  Normal   Started    6m30s (x5 over 8m1s)    kubelet, docker-desktop  Started container sqlserver1
  Warning  BackOff    2m50s (x26 over 7m56s)  kubelet, docker-desktop  Back-off restarting failed container
```

[image]

and the result of: `kubectl log sqlserver-68865dd9f8-7xrtp`

```
log is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use logs instead.
Error: The evaluation period has expired.
This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running at Fri Apr 10 09:28:13 2020
The following diagnostic information is available:

       Reason: 0x00000003
      Message: Unexpected call to legacy ABI.
   Stacktrace: 00005624f716fab4 00005624f716f645 00005624f70b2cbe
               00005624f70f6b17
      Process: 1 - sqlservr
       Thread: 6
  Instance Id: e667ce1e-2281-4bf1-a82c-5ee7f67cef46
     Crash Id:
  Build stamp: 05d4bbaeb108ea432efd44222e380bef8c0a58f369e177ebabf61c807e4b3893
    Timestamp: Fri Apr 10 09:28:13 2020
```

Notice the Error: The evaluation period has expired.
I have noticed that if I go into: deployment.yaml and change the image line to:

image: microsoft/mssql-server-linux

then it works i.e. I can connect via SQL Studio Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After couple tries I see that there is a same problem with all `2019-CTP-*` [images](https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/mssql/server/tags/list).

```
"2019-CTP2.0",
"2019-CTP2.0-ubuntu",
"2019-CTP2.1",
"2019-CTP2.1-ubuntu",
"2019-CTP2.2",
"2019-CTP2.2-ubuntu",
"2019-CTP2.3",
"2019-CTP2.3-ubuntu",
"2019-CTP2.4",
"2019-CTP2.4-ubuntu",
"2019-CTP2.5",
"2019-CTP2.5-ubuntu",
"2019-CTP3.0",
"2019-CTP3.0-ubuntu",
"2019-CTP3.1",
"2019-CTP3.1-ubuntu",
"2019-CTP3.2",
"2019-CTP3.2-ubuntu",
```

NO issues at all with [Featured](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) `2019-CU4-ubuntu-16.04` version.
Suggest you use different from `CTP` version

```
$ kubectl get pods | grep sql
sqlserver-55c86b7c8b-2wrb7   1/1     Running   0          5m58s
```